# Follow what you see

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

### What is the phrase I'm looking for?

---

```
     • 3x3
```

↑↑→→↓←←→→↓

↑↑→→↓←←(→→↓)

↑↑→→↓←←(→→↓)

→→↓↓←←↑↑

↓↓(→↑)(→↓)↑↑

←←↓→→↓←←

←←↓→→←←↓→→

↑↑←←↓↓→→(←↑)

↓↓→→↑↑

←←↓→→←←↓→→

↑↑(→→↓↓)↑↑

←←↓↓→→

←←↓→→←←↓→→

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> **ARROW SEQUENCE**

Because if you...

> ...draw a 3x3 grid of dots and draw the shown arrows in sequence in the only way that fits entirely within the 3x3 grid, you spell out the following letters:
>
>  [image: ARROW SEQUENCE spelled out]
>
>  Note that where arrows are grouped in brackets, the arrows themselves are not drawn but instead a diagonal line is drawn directly to the position that would ultimately be reached if those lines *had* been drawn out.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase you are looking for is:

> ARROW SEQUENCE

> The 3x3 hints to use a three by three grid of dots.
>  And following the directions of the arrows (drawing diagonals where they are in parentheses) gives you the letters of the answer.

Comment: Ha, it's a 3-way tie!